# Symbolic Subset Sum Problem

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, combinatorics, subset

I am interested in solving the following problem with Mathematica, but I do not know if it can be done or how it could be done.

Given a finite set of terms $M=\{a_i(p_1, \ldots,p_m) \}_{i=1}^n$, where each term $a_i$ is a function of $(p_1, \ldots,p_m)$, I would like to identify all subsets $V \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ of these terms, such that $$\sum_{j \in V} a_j=0$$

I think this problem can be regarded as a symbolic version of the subset sum problem. $n$ and $m$ are not large, but large enough that I do not want to do this by hand.

Secondly, if I want to allow other operations apart from addition, say subtraction or multiplication is there any other way than just augmenting the ground set $M$? If not, can I easily rule out trivial solutions like $a_1 - a_1 = 0$.

(Please suggest suitable tags if you know any better.)

As a simple example consider

```
M:={-(1-p1)^2/p2, (1-p1/p2)^2, 
(1-p1^2/p2^2)(1-p2), (1-p2)^2/p2}
```

where a possible solution is to take all elements in the set.

Comment: Please provide a sample `M`.  Thanks.

Comment: You can turn the elements into vectors based on coefficient lists and then it really is the usual subset sum problem.

Comment: I am new to Mathematica. Would you please be able to provide me with a code snippet by any chance? I am unsure how I would imlement what you suggested. :(

Comment: Something along these lines: `In[94]:= m = 
  p2^2 {-(1 - p1)^2/
     p2, (1 - p1/p2)^2, (1 - p1^2/p2^2) (1 - p2), (1 - p2)^2/p2};

In[95]:= lps = Map[Flatten[CoefficientList[#, {p1, p2}, 3]] &, m]

Out[95]= {{0, -1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, -2, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}`